# run scripts if on certain page - rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, if-statement, controller

Would it be a bad idea to run an if statement on each page load to check whether or not I should run a script. For example I have a really long javascript file that only needs to be run when using forms. But currently in each of my files I have included the `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function()` which means it runs on every page load.

In my script I am tempted to write an if statement at the beginning of the file like so:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  controller = $('body').data('controller')
  action = $('body').data('action')
  if controller == foo && action == bar 
    runScripts();
  else
    return;
  function runscripts() {
    ...
```

I'm still somewhat new to using javascript with rails so I don't know of another way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can scope the body element of the layout with the **controller** and **action** name.

```
<body class="<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>">
  <%= yield %>
</body>
```

Now by using the classes we added to the body of the layout, we can limit the pages certain functionality.

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  if (!($(".foo.bar").length > 0)) {
    return;
  }
  //--- page specific js code after above condition ---
});
```

In this case, a small condition can prevent the page specific behaviour being triggered on pages it shouldn’t be.

For more clarity read [this](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/organizing-javascript-in-rails-application-with-turbolinks/)